# How to move cards down separately inside ZStack?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a card deck inside ZStack and I would like to move cards down one by one. I am trying to achieve that when the moving card hit the bottom, the upcoming card should start moving down. The problem I faced is that the whole ZStack is moving down instead of one card.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct Card: Identifiable {
    
    let id = UUID()
    let color: Color
    let name: String
}

struct CardView: View {
    
    let card: Card
        
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(card.color)
            .frame(width: 120, height: 120)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .overlay(
                Text(card.name)
                    .font(.headline)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            )
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var cards: [Card] = [
        Card(color: Color.red, name: "First Card"),
        Card(color: Color.green, name: "Second Card"),
        Card(color: Color.orange, name: "Third Card"),
    ]
    
    @State var timer = Timer.publish(every: 0.1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    @State var movingDownSpeed = CGPoint(x: 0, y:10)
    @State var cardPosition = CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width * 0.5, y:75)

 
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            ForEach(cards) { card in
               CardView(card: card)
                    .position(cardPosition)
                    .onReceive(self.timer) { _ in
                        moveDown()
                    }
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    func moveDown() {
        if cardPosition.y < UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 120 {
            withAnimation(.default){
                cardPosition.y += movingDownSpeed.y
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You have one state for all cards and one timer handler for each cards, so on change of state all card views react and animated to bottom. You should rework logic to have separated positions for each card and some kind of *current* card to animate cards serially.

Comment: I've realized my mistakes thank you. If I store each card's position in a card struct do you think that would be logical? I've tried but I cannot edit struct's properties even by using "mutating func" keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
struct TestView: View {
    var cards: [Card] = [
        Card(color: Color.red, name: "First Card"),
        Card(color: Color.green, name: "Second Card"),
        Card(color: Color.orange, name: "Third Card"),
    ]
    
    @State var timer = Timer.publish(every: 1, on: .main, in: .common).autoconnect()
    @State var movingDownSpeed = CGPoint(x: 0, y:120)
    @State var cardPosition = CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width * 0.5, y:75)
    
    @State var cardPositions = [CGPoint]()
    @State var count = 0

 
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ForEach(self.cardPositions.indices, id: \.self) { index in
               CardView(card: cards[index])
                    .position(cardPositions[index])
            }
        }
        .onReceive(self.timer) { _ in
            moveDown()
        }
        .onAppear() {
            cardPositions = Array(repeating: CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width * 0.5, y:75), count:  cards.count)
            
        }
        
    }
    
    func moveDown() {
        if count < cardPositions.count {
            if cardPositions[count].y < UIScreen.main.bounds.height - 120 {
                withAnimation(.default){
                    cardPositions[count].y += movingDownSpeed.y
                }
            }
            count += 1
            if count == cardPositions.count {
                count = 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```